# GPS coordinates parsing and rendering - Java library?

Tags: java, gps

I often need to parse and render GPS coordinates in different formats. I thought there must be a Java library that includes this functionality as GPS coordinates manipulation seems to be such a common task.
I haven't been able to find anything apart from very simple parsers supporting only one GPS format.
 I know that there are various code snippets in tutorials on the Web. Still, I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RouteConverter](http://www.routeconverter.de/en) is a tool that reads, displays, manipulates and writes a large number of different GPS track formats. It's written in Java, and the parsing/conversion functionality is accessible via an API (there's a "command line" version for download that lacks the GUI modules and is ideal for this purpose).